# Google Sheets / How to change the format of cells whose values are the same as the values from the array?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Please, tell How to change the visual content in a cell (background, font-weight and color), provided that the value stored in this cell matches the value of the array being checked?
[image]
I watched on [ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#ConditionalFormatRule) and try to write script to decide this problem on nodejs

```
const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
)

const gsapi = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth: client
})

const spreadsheetIdCurr = '1pircQiSbWuiaMVOVFi9ZfVizB5KEx4YSh7FqdWEp4_f';

const checkData = {values: ["aaa", "b"]}; // Arrey for checking

async function colorizeResult() {

    res = await gsapi.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetIdCurr,
        requestBody: {
            requests: [
                {
                    updateCells: {
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 0,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 5,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    addConditionalFormatRule: {
                        rule: {
                            booleanRule: {
                                condition: {
                                    type: "ONE_OF_LIST",
                                    values: [{userEnteredFormat: {userEnteredValue: checkData[0]}},
                                        {userEnteredFormat: {userEnteredValue: checkData[1]}},],
                                },
                                format: {
                                    textFormat: {
                                        bold: true,
                                        foregroundColor: {red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1}
                                    },
                                    backgroundColor: {red: 0.1, green: 0.3, blue: 1}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        },
    })

}
colorizeResult();
```

..., but it doesn't work. I got a message `(node:10700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'addConditionalFormatRule'`

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the conditional format rule to the range of "A1:E2" using the values of "aaa" or "b".
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In your request body, `updateCells` is not used.
- In your situation, I thought that `CUSTOM_FORMULA` instead of `ONE_OF_LIST` might be suitable.

When these points are reflected to your request body, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
async function colorizeResult() {
  res = await gsapi.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetIdCurr,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          addConditionalFormatRule: {
            rule: {
              booleanRule: {
                condition: {
                  type: "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                  values: [
                    {
                      userEnteredValue: `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"${checkData.values.map(e => `^${e}\$`).join("|")}")`, // Modified
                    },
                  ],
                },
                format: {
                  textFormat: {
                    bold: true,
                    foregroundColor: {
                      red: 1,
                      green: 1,
                      blue: 1,
                    },
                  },
                  backgroundColor: {
                    red: 0.1,
                    green: 0.3,
                    blue: 1,
                  },
                },
              },
              ranges: [
                {
                  sheetId: 0,
                  startColumnIndex: 0,
                  endColumnIndex: 5,
                  startRowIndex: 0,
                  endRowIndex: 2,
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- When this script is run several times, the conditional format rule is added. In this answer, I modified your request body for removing your current issue. For example, I thought that if you want to update the existing the conditional format rule, you can also use `UpdateConditionalFormatRuleRequest`.
- This modified script supporses that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful this.
- If `` userEnteredValue: `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"${checkData.values.map(e => `^${e}\$`).join("|")}")`, `` was not useful for your actual situation, please modify it to `` userEnteredValue: `=OR(${checkData.values.map(e => `A1="${e}"`).join(",")})`, `` and test it again. I think that both script will be the same result.

#### References:

- [AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addconditionalformatrulerequest)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's work wrong for my task.  I need to colorize cells if they value matches the arrays values. Exact match. I showed it on a picture  ` const checkData = {values: ["aaa", "b"]}; // Arrey for checking ` Your script colored cells but with according to an incomprehensible logic.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `but it's work wrong for my task.`, I couldn't understand detail of your current issue.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Becanse when I tested my proposed modified script, your error of `Error: Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'addConditionalFormatRule'` doesn't occur and the background color of cells which have the values of "aaa" and "b" are changed. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize that my test worked fine. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detail of it? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thanks for help. I increased the search range. I got this result. http://joxi.ru/Dr8Yxd5sKkyyEm  This is a strange result for array ["aaa", "b"]. In a real task, I'm trying to colorize the URL addresses from a large dynamically loaded array. For example, if we have an array of comparison ``` const checkData = {values: ["https://www.amazon.com/iHealth-Thermometer-Vibration-Notification-Thermopile/", "https://www.amazon.com/Gaiam-Classic-Balance-Ball-Chair/dp/B01DUYIOFU/"]}; ```  and if we use your script it would be weird result

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Thank you for replying. By your additional information, I could understand it. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 And, if ``userEnteredValue: `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"${checkData.values.map(e => `^${e}\$`).join("|")}")`,`` was not useful for your actual situation, please modify it to ``userEnteredValue: `=OR(${checkData.values.map(e => `A1="${e}"`).join(",")})`,`` and test it again. I think that both script will be the same result.

Comment: Yes thanks, it's work for simple example now. (First formula). Unfortunately, for urls checking this formula don't work, especially if we need an exact match

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.